# Loop in Loop - Performing an error check

Tags: python-3.x

The code checks for a User ID `(id_usager)`. If it doesn't check out, it performs the else as an error catch. If it does check out, it calls in the other functions and prints `("Pour la personne"etc)`. That being said, I want my program to continue onto `autreRecommandation` afterwards, however as it stands, it exits after the aforementioned print.

```
while True:
    id_check = True
    while id_check:
        id_usager = input("Entrer l'ID de l'usager pour lequel vous voulez une recommandation (entre 0 et {}): ".format(n - 1))

        if id_usager.isdigit():
            if int(id_usager) in range(n):
                id_usager = int(id_usager)
                calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
                print("Pour la personne", id_usager, ", nous recommandons l'ami", recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite), ".")
                return id_check == True
            else:
                print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")

        else:
            print("Erreur: l'usager doit être un nombre entier entre ", 0, "et", n - 1, "inclusivement.\n")

    autreRecommandation = input("Voulez-vous une autre recommandation (oui/non)?")
    if autreRecommandation.lower() == "oui":
        return True
    else:
        print("Merci d'avoir utiliser le programme de recommandation d'amis.")
        break
```

Comment: Don't print error messages in your business logic. Raise an exception at each error point, and print the excelption in one place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return id_check == True` statement will return control to the caller of your function. 
Instead you could use the `break` statement to come out of the inner while loop and the control will then return to the outer while loop and go to `autreRecommandation` as expected.

The code could be more like

```
calculer_scores_similarite(reseau)
print("Pour la personne", id_usager, ", nous recommandons l'ami",recommander(id_usager, reseau, matrice_similarite), ".")
id_check == True
break
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the keyword [`continue`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#continue) ?

Comment: I just used continue and it was the same problem. I changed the code by removing the initial loop and integrating the 2nd input prompt right after the first and that gives the results I needed.